# Put all first similar chars of each of two string into another string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, compare

In my iOS app I have two NSStrings: "One two three" and "one two ten".
I need all first similar chars of each string to be placed into another NSString "one two t"
Any help please.

Comment: You should post what you have tried (code) in your question so that we can assist you.

Comment: I can make an array of chars from each string and then compare array elements with similar index and put these chars into new string until elements are equal. But maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *firstString = @"One two three";
NSString *secondString = @"One two ten";

NSString *shorterString;
NSString *longerString;

if (firstString.length >= secondString.length) {
    shorterString = secondString;
    longerString = firstString;
} else {
    shorterString = firstString;
    longerString = secondString;
}

NSString *newString = @"";

int index = 0;

while ([[shorterString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)] isEqualToString: [longerString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)]]  && index < shorterString.length ) {
    newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:[shorterString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)]];
    index++;
}
NSLog(newString);
```

Comment: If you do not care about the case type of the letter then you will have to change your strings to all uppercase or all lowercase then compare